# Can I programme the alternate screen of Linux terminal with Node(or Python)?

Tags: python, node.js, terminal

CLI applications like Vim, cdargs can open a new screen then allow users to draw characters there. I'd like to try making some tools like that with Node and was told that it was called "alternative screen"(?).

I'm familiar with JS. But if there's not a solution, Python maybe(..) OK. Want some code example please :)

Found a modules according to tMC's anwser, trying to figure out...
https://github.com/mscdex/node-ncurses

Comment: Do you want this to work on a command prompt? If so, what does that have to do with Node.js?  If not, I don't understand your reference to vim and cdargs.  It is extrememly unclear what you are asking- but you might want to investigate ncurses if you are talking about a terminal application.

Comment: ToT , I'm no good at English... I want to make a small tool to change from directories, which draws directories on the screen and `cd`s into (or out) directories on my keystrokes. I want it to work in the terminal. So this question was focused on that.

Comment: Node.js is for writing web servers, so that's probably not what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vim uses the `ncurses` library to do drawing. You have already found a Node.JS bindings, so you should have no trouble using this library within your application.

I propose you to read the [NCURSES tutorial](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/) and attempt to do it in Node.JS.